# How to duplicate this javascript function without effecting original code

Tags: javascript, function, slider, duplicates

I am trying to duplicate this code without effecting the original code.

Issue: 
When clicking on for rent the price range slider changes to 0-1000
But when I click on rented the price range slider changes to 0m-5m

How can I duplicate this code and change te price range slider for rented to 0-1000?
Tried to duplicate the original code and change the value for-rent to rented, not working.
I have searched on the internet for duplicating functions but it is to complicated for me to understand.

Javascript code:

```
this.createPriceSlider = function( status ) {
            this.priceSlider.rangeSlider({
                minPriceInput       : 'input#price-from',
                maxPriceInput       : 'input#price-to',
                minPriceDisplayElem : '.min-price-display',
                maxPriceDisplayElem : '.max-price-display',
                currencySymbol      : localizations.currencySymbol,
                range               : true,
                min                 :  status == 'for-rent' ? parseInt( listingSearchVars.priceSliderRentalMin ) : parseInt( listingSearchVars.priceSliderMin ),
                max                 : status == 'for-rent' ? parseInt( listingSearchVars.priceSliderRentalMax ) : parseInt( listingSearchVars.priceSliderMax ),
                values              : 'auto',
                step                : status == 'for-rent' ? parseInt( listingSearchVars.priceSliderRentalStep ) : parseInt( listingSearchVars.priceSliderStep )
            });
        };

        this.restartPriceSlider = function( status ) {
            if ( status !== this.currentListingStatus ) {
                this.currentListingStatus = status;
                this.priceSlider.slider( 'destroy' );

                var minVal = status == 'for-rent' ? parseInt( listingSearchVars.priceSliderRentalMin ) : parseInt( listingSearchVars.priceSliderMin ),
                    maxVal = status == 'for-rent' ? parseInt( listingSearchVars.priceSliderRentalMax ) : parseInt( listingSearchVars.priceSliderMax );

                $( '#price-from' ).val( minVal );
                $( '#price-to' ).val( maxVal );
                this.createPriceSlider( status );
            }
        };
```

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @ArrayKnight I would but it contains php code so I think it would not work in Jsfiddle.

Comment: Finally I have solved this issue,

I changed every peace of this code status == 'for-rent' to status = 'for-rent' && 'rented'